# ASP.Net Core 2.1: pass urlencoded "id" through routing?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.Net Core 2.1.  I have a `<ul>` list on the index page and one of the items in the list (generated from a database) has a "/" in the name.  The list item is generated as:

```
    <li>
        <a href="/Home/Index/OBJECT-WITH-A-%2F-IN-IT">OBJECT-WITH-A-/-IN-IT</a>
    </li>
```

If I click on the resulting link I get the 404 error:

```
    No webpage was found for the web address:
    https://localhost:12345/Home/Index/OBJECT-WITH-A-%2F-IN-IT
```

My guess is that the routing stuff is doing a URL Decode at some point before I want it to in this case.  Is there a way to pass this `{id}` through  as is?

**Edit**

I tried the things below and I marked the best answer for me but due to other issues I rolled back my changes and my initial state just started working.  I do not understand why but thanks again.

Comment: are you using razor for your web? add the markup code and also the controller action here too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an asterisk (*) or double asterisk (**) as a prefix to a route parameter to bind to the rest of the URI. These are called a catch-all parameters.

```
app.UseMvc(
    routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "defaults",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{*id}");
    }
);
```

You could refer [Route template reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#route-template-reference)

Answer (score 0):

With the following configuration you example works fine

**Startup.cs**

```
/..
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
//or its equivalent
app.UseMvc(routes => {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController {
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(string id) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Value of `id` becomes equal to `"OBJECT-WITH-A-%2F-IN-IT"`. In case of link generated as following

```
<a href="/Home/Index/OBJECT-WITH-A-/-IN-IT">OBJECT-WITH-A-/-IN-IT</a>
```

it really returns `404 Not Found`.

Comment: Thanks, that is my configuration.  For me it doesn't seem to matter if the `href` in the link tag has the `/` or `%2F` string.  I get the 404 in either case.